# PHP Sendmail Not Working

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I am working on website for my company and I want customers to be able to fill out an HTML form and have it send an email to both myself and the customer via php. Here is my code, right now when I click submit after filling out the form I get my php echo, but neither email sends. Thanks in advanced! (both codes are in one file named quotes.php)

```
<form action="quotes.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" required="yes"><br>
            Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required="yes"><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" required="yes"><br>
            Home or Business?: <input type="text" name="horb" required="yes"><br>
            Number of int. Cameras Desired: <input type="number" name="extcam"><br>
            Number of ext. Cameras Desired: <input type="number" name="intcam"><br>
            Number of ext. Doors: <input type="number" name="exdrs"><br>
            Do/Don't want Automated Door Locks?: <input type="text" name="locks"><br>
            Number of 1st Floor Windows: <input type="number" name="winds"><br>
            Number of Windows on Other Floors: <input type="number" name="otherwinds">     <br>
            Do/Don't want Energy Control?: <input type="text" name="energy"><br>
            Number of Switches to be Controlled:<input type="number" name="switches"><br>
            Number of Outlets to be Controlled:<input type="number" name="outlets"><br>
            Do/Don't want Automated Thermostat?: <input type="text" name="temp"><br>
            <textarea type="text" rows="4" cols="50" name="comments">Any additional devices/comments...</textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br>
            <small>*Please note a walk-through of the property may be neccessary before a final price can be determined.</small>
        </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "norcalhomeautomation@gmail.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Quote form submission!";
    $subject2 = "Confirmation of your Quote Request";
    $message = $name . " requested a quote for their " . $_POST['horb'] . ":" . "\n\n" . "The customer requested " . $_POST['extcam'] . " exterior cameras and " . $_POST['intcam'] . " interior cameras. They have " . $_POST['extdrs'] . " exterior doors they " . $_POST['locks'] . " want automated locks for. They have " . $_POST['winds'] . " windows on the first floor and " . $_POST['otherwinds'] . " other windows. They " . $_POST['energy'] . " want energy control and they have " . $_POST['switches'] . " switches and " . $_POST['outlets'] . " outlets to be replaced. They " . $_POST['temp'] . " want an automated thermostat. The customer commented the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['comments'] . ". You may contact them at either " . $_POST['email'] . " or " . $_POST['phone'] . "at your earliest convenience.";
    $message2 = "Thank you for your quote request " . $_POST['name'] . "! This email is to confirm your quote was successfully received by NorCal Home Automation. A representative from NorCal will contact you shortly at either " . $_POST['email'] . " or " . $_POST['phone'] . ". If this contact information was entered incorrectly please email NorCalHomeAutomation@gmail.com to update your contact information. Thank you for your interest in NorCal Home Automation we look forward to having you as a satisfied customer!";

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
    echo "Thank you " . $name . " your quote was submitted, please check your email for confirmation.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server has sendmail setup? Then, did you do the simplest test case for sending an email? Then did you check that any emails weren't getting lost in the spam folder, or that your IP is not banned for past spammy activities? There are lots of things that can go wrong here; you need to debug and check your server's error logging.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to check into a third party service like Sendgrid.

Comment: I know the server has SMTP setup, but I'm not sure if it allows sendmail I'll check if there is an error log. It's just on free web hosting right now because I wanted to make sure everything worked so maybe thats why I will be upgrading to paid when I'm ready to launch. Thank you!

edit: just checked and the error logs are available only once I switch to paid so I guess I will troubleshoot this problem last once I switch thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check and see if the php instance is configured to allow the use of the mail() command.

Also, instead of using two separate commands, embed a "Bcc:" in the header like this:

```
$headers.= "Bcc: $from\n";
```

Comment: thank you for that header suggestion i will do that! They won't let me edit the php.ini on the free hosting but i know i will be able to once i switch to paid so hopefully thats what's wrong thanks!